# How can we use splint using cmake for large project

Tags: cmake, splint

I am trying to use splint on moderately large project which uses cmake for build.
Project contains hundreds of source file scattered over large directory structure. I am not finding any info for using splint with cmake.

directory structure is like

```
|-- CMakeLists.txt

|-- dir1

    |-- CMakeLists.txt

    |-- src

        '-- file1.c

    |-- include

        '-- file1.h


|-- dir2

    |-- CMakeLists.txt

    |-- src

        '-- file2.c 

    |-- include

        '-- file2.h
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me Google it for you. For "cmake splint" Google gives [this link](https://github.com/fmrl/ramalloc/blob/master/cmake/splint.cmake) as 2nd result.

You can use it in your project if license permits, or just use it as reference when writing your own module. It is very simple, all it does is call `splint` executable with needed flags on requested sources using cmake's `add_custom_target` command.